# Format the maximum value of a column with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I try to format the cell with the maximum value in a column.

I tried two approaches:

First approach:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color' : '#FFC7CE'}) 

sheet1.conditional_format('AQ{i}:AQ{j}'.format(i=2,j=len(df)+1),
                  {'type': 'top',
                   'value': '1/len(df)'
                   'cirteria' : %
                   'format' : format1})
```

this approach partly works, beacuse with my understanding, the 'value' property accepts only integers.

Meaning, if i want to get the "maximum" value out of 1000 numbers, i cant use 0.001.
(Suppose they are all distinct of course.)

Second approach:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color' : '#FFC7CE'})

sheet1.conditional_format('AQ{i}:AQ{j}'.format(i=2,j=len(df)+1),
                  {'type': 'formula',
                   'cirteria' : '=max(AQ$2:AQ$1000)',
                   'format' : format1})
```

This approcah doesnt work at all, i guess im not working right with the formula type.

I would like to understand the right solution.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't think we can check for the maximum value in the conditional_format method, but it might be better to read the column into a List, get the index of the largest value using Max(), and use the index to specify the range in a write method along with the format. If this approach works for you, I can create sample code for you to try

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a conditional format using the `top 1` type/criteria, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [10, 20, 30, 20, 99, 30, 15]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_conditional.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

# Green fill with dark green text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#C6EFCE",
                               "font_color": "#006100"})

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Apply a conditional format to the required cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format(
    1, max_col, max_row, max_col,
    {"type": "top", "value": 1, "format": format1}
)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]